# How can I access the keys from the below local json file?

Tags: angular

I want to access all the keys present in the local json file. When I am using Object.keys(data) it is returnning the 0. I had checked the output in the console,by default the output of json is mapped to 0. So please let me know how can I access the keys.

```
    public ngOnInit(){
        this._logger.info("Header Mapping Component Initialized");
        this.httpClient.get("applauncher/input.json").subscribe(res=>{
            this.products=res;
            this.keys=Object.keys(this.products);
            console.log("Mapping data",this.keys);
        });


input.json



[
{
    "College1": [
        [
            "Studname1"
        ],
        [
            "Studname2"
        ]
    ],
    "College2": [
        [
            "Stud1"
        ]
    ],
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```js
const list = [{
  "College1": [
    [
      "Studname1"
    ],
    [
      "Studname2"
    ]
  ],
  "College2": [
    [
      "Stud1"
    ]
  ],
}]
const keys = list.map(item => Object.keys(item));

console.log(keys[0]);
```

Output => ["College1", "College2"]

Comment: The data which you have given in the list is there in my json file. So how can store the json data in the list

Comment: put your json file in assets folder and simply do this.http.get('relative_path_to_file').subscribe((resp) => this,list = resp);

Comment: Then how can I access the keys because above code is not working if I am reading the  data from json file

Comment: If you are getting resp then just do resp.map(item => Object.keys(item));

Comment: Not working...throwing an error property map does not exist on object...Map is already imported